# Need help on comparing values between 2 columns based on common column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I have 6 columns as listed below where first 3 are coming from one source and rest 3 are from different.
I want to compare values that are missing or additional in column B and E by comparing against common columns A,D between 2 different sources. Can you please help me with formula to find matching result, thanks in advance.

```
A       B       C       D       E       F
PKG1    Code1   $10     PKG1    Code1   $10 
PKG1    Code2   $20     PKG1    Code2   $20 
PKG1    Code3   $30     PKG2    Code1   $40 
PKG2    Code1   $40     PKG2    Code2   $50 
PKG2    Code2   $50     PKG2    Code3   $60 
PKG2    Code3   $60
```

Adding picture excel incase if above format is confusing:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `COUNTIFS()` like in this way-

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(D:D,A1,E:E,B1)>=1,"Match Found","Nop")
```

[image]

Comment: In the above table if there is price difference between codes from 2 lists of A and B could you please let me know how to find it @Harun24HR

Comment: Is there any chance to have duplicate entry. Then need to use array type formula other wise we can use `sumifs()` instaed of `countifs()`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to make a concatenated column and then use vlookup how you are used to. For example, insert a new column d using the formula =a2&b2&c2. Then insert a new h as well using the formula =e2&f2&g2.

Now you just use vlookup the normal way on the concatenated columsn. =vlooup(d1,h:h,1,false)

Comment: This has the potential to count false positives. A better option might be COUNTIFS.

Comment: I usually run it both ways. vlookup combaring d to h and vlookup comparing h to d so i can see which items are in one list but not the other. It assumes there are no duplicates. If there is the potential for duplicates countifs would be a better idea

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Hooded_0ne